# Cast Json object to another class object in android

Tags: java, android, casting, json

I am new in Android.
 I want to do a cast JSON object to particular class object. 
Just like

```
TestClass test = (TestClass) jsonObject.
```

Is it possible?

Comment: No, you should parse JSON object.

Comment: You can only cast from A to B if A is derived from B ( `extends` or `implements` or if A == B)

Comment: This is nothing specific to Android. Learn Java

Comment: Yes, I got your inheritance point but I am asking about the ways. I got the solution by creating get and set methods. thanx for reply

Comment: use `GSON` library like this 
`JSONObject userData = null; // I am getting this object as parameter 
        Gson gson= new Gson();
        User objUser = gson.fromJson(userData.toString(),User.class);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply casting is not possible. You should get all the values from the JSON Object and set the values to your Object of the other class using getter and setter methods.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at on GSON (http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), or parse the JSON yourself

Answer (score 0):

Please go with this one , it will solve your problem.

```
http://kylewbanks.com/post/show/Tutorial-Android-Parsing-JSON-with-GSON 

http://huluyige.blogspot.in/2013/02/android-code-snippetusing-gson-to-parse.html
```